# Custom Library Components Does not show required props on intellisense

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, rollupjs

I developed a custom React component library to be consume on a private npm. All my components are Typescript React Class Components and in many I used interfaces to declare which props are optional or required. Example:

```
export interface ICardLinkProps {

    Title: string;
    Description: string;
    ActionText: string;
    DestinationUrl?: string;
    ImageUrl?: string;
    Icon?: string;
    Theme: Theme;
}

export class CardLink extends React.Component<ICardLinkProps> {
   /// component Code.
}
```

All the components work as expected but when my coworkers install de package the intellisense does not show the required props. Example:

[image: No intellinse]

In contrast if I consume a component from Material-UI the intellisense shows all  required and optional props.

[image: yes Intellinse]

Does anyone have an idea on Why I am not getting the intellisense for my components? I'm using rollup to export build the package, this is my configuration:

```
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import commonjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";
import external from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import resolve from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve";
import url from "rollup-plugin-url";
import PeerDepsExternalPlugin from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";

import pkg from "./package.json";


export default {
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: "cjs",
      exports: "named",
      sourcemap: true
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: "es",
      exports: "named",
      sourcemap: true
    }
  ],
  plugins: [

    url({
      include: ['**/*.ttf', '**/*.png'],
      limit: Infinity
    }),
    PeerDepsExternalPlugin(),
    external(),
    resolve(),
    typescript({
      rollupCommonJSResolveHack: true,
      exclude: "**/__tests__/**",
      clean: true
    }),
    commonjs({
      include: ["node_modules/**"],
      namedExports: {
        "node_modules/react/react.js": [
          "Children",
          "Component",
          "PropTypes",
          "createElement"
        ],
        "node_modules/react-dom/index.js": ["render"],
        'node_modules/react-is/index.js': [
          'isElement',
          'isValidElementType',
          'ForwardRef',
          'Memo',
          'isFragment'
        ],
        'node_modules/prop-types/index.js': [
          'elementType'
        ]
      }
    })
  ]
};
```

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom",
      "es2016",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "src/types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "src/**/*.stories.tsx",
    "src/**/*.test.tsx"
  ]
}
```

Here is the dist folder after runing rollup -c:

[image: componentsDts]

[image: rootfolder]

This is the contents of the CardLink.d.ts

```
import React from "react";
import { ICardLinkProps } from "./ICardLinkProps";
/**
 * CardLink Component
 * @extends {Component<ICardLinkProps,ICardLinkState>}
 */
export declare const CardLink: React.ComponentType<Pick<Pick<ICardLinkProps, "theme" | "classes"> & Partial<Pick<ICardLinkProps, "Title" | "Description" | "ActionText" | "DestinationUrl" | "ImageUrl" | "Icon" | "Secondary">> & Partial<Pick<{
    Title: string;
    Description: string;
    ActionText: string;
    DestinationUrl: string;
    ImageUrl: string;
    Icon: string;
    Secondary: boolean;
}, never>>, "Title" | "Description" | "ActionText" | "DestinationUrl" | "ImageUrl" | "Icon" | "Secondary"> & import("@material-ui/core").StyledComponentProps<"centeredIcon" | "icon" | "bellowMargin" | "paper" | "paperSecondary" | "iconSecondary" | "container" | "actionsArea">>;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see your tsconfig.json?

Comment: Sure, let me update my question.

Comment: When you look in the build folder that rollup generates, are there any .d.ts files in there?

Comment: @SethLutske Yes, Updating question with the rollup output

Comment: Ok...what's the actual content of the CarLink.d.ts file?

Comment: @SethLutske added the content of the .d.ts

Comment: I deleted my answer because the issues is clearly not the lack of .d.ts files being output.  But now the question has enough info to fully describe the problem you're having with your specific build environment